# Login Facebook (Thread 1 signal SIGABRT) con SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, swift, xcode, facebook

Intento probar mi app con la funcionalidad de facebook y de google pero se cuelga y sale `Thread 1 signal SIGABRT`, en la consola del debug sale que debo agregar un key en el info.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion fue que como agregue los dos metodos tanto google como facebook

> CFBundleURLTypes

se genero un error, mi solucion fue muy simple

lo remplace en un solo codigo